# ios/objective-c: How can I prevent exception when inserting Null into core data?

Tags: ios, core-data, null

I would think that the following code would not throw an exception if the value is null but is is.  Am I missing a typo or is there a different way to do this?

```
if (![itemid isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
                {
            [record setValue:itemid forKey:@"itemid"];
            }

Throws exception 'itemid    NSNumber *  (null)  0x14e8ebc0'
```

Comment: Here you are checking the value is null or not. If its null then you are not assigning the value to record. So anyway the record value is null. Just set else part and feed some value to record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If itemid is nil (as opposed to an instance of the NSNull class), then -isKindOfClass: will return NO, and it will pass the condition and will try to set the value.

So, you probably want `if (itemid && ![itemid isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) { ...`.

A message to a nil reference returns nil, or 0 or false in a numeric / bool context, regardless of the arguments to that message.

Comment: if itemid is id, you can also use: if ((itemid != nil) && (itemid != [NSNull null]))